# How to sort a table from SQL using variable in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sorting, variables, html-table

I have a problem in sorting table from information took from SQL database. I need to sort the table with PHP variable $points (which is count from two different fields in SQL database and printed as last part of the table so the points IS NOT included in SQL).

So basically I need to sort the table by $points without saving any information about points directly to the SQL database.

I wonder what would be the simplest way to do it if it is possible?

And the PHP code is down here:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['button'])) {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Points_database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Error: ", mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Points_table;";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    echo "<table><tr><td>Team</td><td>Games</td><td>Wins</td><td>Tie</td><td>Losses</td><td>Goals</td><td>Points</td></tr>";
    $rowcount=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $rowcount++;
        $points= $row['wins'] * 3 + $row['tie'];
        if($rowcount%2==0) {
            echo "<tr class='rowstyle2'>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<tr>"; 
        }
        echo "<td>".$row['team']."</td><td>".$row['games']."</td><td>".$row['wins']."</td><td>".$row['tie']."</td><td>".$row['losses']."</td><td>".$row['goals']."</td><td>".$points."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: what are values for count that you created by PHP?

Comment: $rowcount is just for to make every other row in the table colored. Or if you meaned how I count the $points it is based on wins and ties from SQL database

Comment: +1 for the MS Paint table. :D

Comment: Can you just move points calculation to SQL code?

Comment: that is why I got drop off from graphic design school :(

Comment: No I cannot, thats the point :/ otherway it would be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not?

```
SELECT *, (wins*3 + tie) AS pts FROM table ORDER BY pts DESC
```

or if you dont want calculations in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY wins*3 + tie DESC
```

here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2045/4

Comment: Because it is absolute demand for this that I do not insert any data about the points into SQL. Would be very easy if I could do that :/

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY wins*3 + tie DESC` and what is this?

Comment: Seems legit. I am still trying to make $points variable with it in the original program and having some errors but will see soon if it works there.

Comment: For some reason trying to give a value for $points that way does not seem to work correctly

Comment: just replace your 7th line following: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Points_table ORDER BY wins*3 + tie DESC;";` and u'll get sorted array